# Difference between std::greater<int>() and std::greater<int>?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, predicate, functor

This code works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    priority_queue<int,vector<int>,greater<int> > pq;
    pq.push(1);
    cout<<pq.top()<<endl;
}
```

But,this code does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    priority_queue<int,vector<int>,greater<int>() > pq;
    pq.push(1);
    cout<<pq.top()<<endl;
}
```

Why?
All I understand is that `greater<int>()`  is a function object and `priority_queue` accepts a binary predicate as third argument and that predicates are a special type of functors.
But how does the pair of braces make that difference.

Comment: Well, how is a function different from calling a function?

Comment: `std::greater<int>` is a type, with () it becomes a constructor call

Comment: Because the third template argument is supposed to be a *type* and not an object?

Comment: I don't really get the question. Why are you surprised that adding random parenthesis to C++ code causes compilation errors?

Comment: @Incomputable where can i read about the 'type', over the internet i can find references of 'greater<int>()' version only.

Comment: @Manohar, well, grab a book. There is a list of great books on SO, try to search for it.

Comment: @Incomputable Can you please provide some insight on how a 'type' can compare things. So far I have used and seen only functions, functors and lamdas for comapring.

Comment: @Manohar, types can't compare things. Again, read a good book.

Comment: @Manohar - A type doesn't compare anything. The member function `operator()` that this type defines (and objects of this type can invoke) does the comparison.

Comment: @Manohar  I wonder that your question is down-voted. In fact most of  the comments here are wrong.  This demonstrates that your question is good. I upvoted it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this declaration

```
priority_queue<int,vector<int>,greater<int> > pq;
```

the type template argument `greater<int>` corresponds to the type of a structure.

In this declaration

```
priority_queue<int,vector<int>,greater<int>() > pq;
```

the type template argument `greater<int>()` corresponds to the type of a function that has no parameters and has the return type `greater<int>`

The class template `std::priority_queue` expects that the argument will be of a function object type that is a pointer to function or a class type that has a function operator.

To make it more clear compare for example these declarations

```
std::vector<int()> v1;
```

and

```
std::vector<int (*)()> v2;
```

For the first declaration the compiler will issue an error because the operator sizeof may not be applied to a function type `int()` and the vector will be unable to allocate memory for its elements. Here `int()` used as a type template argument is not an expression. It is a type-id.

In the second declaration the vector deal with pointers to function and it can allocate memory for its elements that are pointers.

Comment: Thank you sir. This was what I was asking for.

Comment: "the type template argument greater<int>() corresponds to the type of a function that has no parameters and has the return type greater<int>"

Isn't `greater<int>()` a temporary function object?

Comment: @ Iamanon It is a type template argument denoting a function type.

Answer (score 3):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

```
template<
     class T,
     class Container = std::vector<T>,
     class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
 > class priority_queue;
```

> Compare   -   A Compare **type** providing a strict weak ordering.

So for *std::priority_queue* you pass a type of comparator as a template parameter.

On the other hand,

```
greater<int>()
```

stands for creation of new object of type `greater<int>` which is not an option in your case.

Comment: Your answer was meaningful. Can you please provide some insight on how a 'type' can compare things. So far I have used and seen only functions, functors and lamdas for comapring.

Comment: @Manohar I guess that *priority_queue* simply creates an instance of *Comparator* to compare things.

Comment: Functions, functors and lambas have a  type.
Since the class/function should accept any of these, they have to be templated. Most of the time (algorithms library etc.) this type is deduced and you dont need to provide it explicitly
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses